# Beautifulsoup - add <br> tag in div text?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Trying to use beautifulsoup to make changes to a html file. I want to add a new line after every bullet point in the div class below. I have already tried text.replace function (using '\n') but it doesn't work outside of the terminal since html only creates new line with a br tag. Is there a way to insert a line break at the end of every bullet point?

HTML code:

`<div class="recipe"> ■ Boil water to high heat ■ Put eggs in water ■ Put on lid ■ Wait 8 - 12 minutes ■ Take out eggs ■ Serve</div>`

When I view it on a webpage it currently looks like this:
■ Boil water to high heat ■ Put eggs in water ■ Put on lid ■ Wait 8 - 12 minutes ■ Take out eggs ■ Serve

I would like it to look like this:
■ Boil water to high heat 
■ Put eggs in water 
■ Put on lid 
■ Wait 8 - 12 minutes
■ Take out eggs 
■ Serve

Code I used to add a new line (only works with print function). Without the print function, it just replaces all the '■' with '\n■' without making a new line in the html file.

```
for div in soup.find_all("div", {'class':'recipe'}): 
    print(div.text.replace('■','\n■'))
```

Comment: I don't get why you aren't using an unordered list. Is there any reason you are not using it?

Comment: I'm just using this as an example. The website that had the bullet points didn't have it in an unordered list, all in the same div class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<div class="recipe">
    ■ Boil water to high heat ■ Put eggs in water ■ Put on lid ■ Wait 8 - 12 minutes ■ Take out eggs ■ Serve
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")
recipe = soup.find(class_="recipe")

t = BeautifulSoup(
    "<br />■ ".join(recipe.get_text(strip=True).split("■")).strip("<br />"),
    "html.parser",
)
recipe.string.replace_with(t)

print(soup.prettify())
```

This will create `<br />` after each `■` item (screenshot from Firefox):

[image]

HTML:

```html
<div class="recipe">
 ■  Boil water to high heat
 <br/>
 ■  Put eggs in water
 <br/>
 ■  Put on lid
 <br/>
 ■  Wait 8 - 12 minutes
 <br/>
 ■  Take out eggs
 <br/>
 ■  Serve
</div>
```

---

EDIT: To save the `soup` to HTML file:

```py
with open("page.html", "w") as f_out:
    f_out.write(str(soup))
```

Comment: Yep that worked! Thanks a lot, that was very fast XD.

Comment: Any idea on how to save the changes to a html file?

Comment: Sweet. Thanks again man, you've been of great help!