# Replacing line breaks with <br> inside a tag using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to parse some `HTML` using `BeautifulSoup` and replace any line breaks (`\n`) that are within `<blockquote>` tags with `<br>` tags. It is extra difficult because the `<blockquote>` may contain other HTML tags.

My current attempt:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<p>Hello
there</p>
<blockquote>Line 1
Line 2
<strong>Line 3</strong>
Line 4</blockquote>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for element in soup.findAll():
    if element.name == "blockquote":
        new_content = BeautifulSoup(
            "<br>".join(element.get_text(strip=True).split("\n")).strip("<br>"),
            "html.parser",
        )
        element.string.replace_with(new_content)

print(str(soup))
```

Output should be:

```html
<p>Hello
there</p>
<blockquote>Line 1<br/>Line 2<br/><strong>Line 3</strong><br/>Line 4</blockquote>
```

However, this code, adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68580682/250962) only works if there are no HTML tags within the `<blockquote>`. But if there are (the `<strong>Line 3</strong>`) then `element.string` is `None`, and the above fails.

Is there an alternative that can cope with HTML tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative would be to use `descendants` to look for `NavigableString`s, and replace just those, leaving other elements alone:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString

html = """
<p>Hello
there</p>
<blockquote>Line 1
Line 2
<strong>Line 3</strong>
Line 4</blockquote>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for quote in soup.find_all("blockquote"):
    for element in list(quote.descendants):
        if type(element) is NavigableString:
            markup = element.string.replace("\n", "<br>")
            element.string.replace_with(BeautifulSoup(markup, "html.parser"))

print(str(soup))
```

Output:

```
<p>Hello
there</p>
<blockquote>Line 1<br/>Line 2<br/><strong>Line 3</strong><br/>Line 4</blockquote>
```

An advantage of this approach is that it doesn't touch, for example, HTML comments:

```
<blockquote>
<!--
a comment
-->
</blockquote>
```

is turned into

```
<blockquote><br/><!--
a comment
--><br/></blockquote>
```

as you might expect.

Comment: Diving deeper into `bs4` and going with check for `NavigableString` in the `descendants` +1

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much! I wouldn't have stumbled upon this myself.

Answer (score 2):

It is much simpler to select your elements more specific and work on the elements itself as `string` while using `replace()`.

This way you don't have to worry about other tags that would otherwise be present as objects and are not represented as string in result of `get_text()`.

```
new_content = BeautifulSoup(
    str(element).replace('\n','<br>'),
    "html.parser",
)
element.replace_with(new_content)
```

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<p>Hello
there</p>
<blockquote>Line 1
Line 2
<strong>Line 3</strong>
Line 4</blockquote>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for element in soup.find_all('blockquote'):
    new_content = BeautifulSoup(
        str(element).replace('\n','<br>'),
        "html.parser",
    )
    element.replace_with(new_content)

print(str(soup))
```

###### Output

```
<p>Hello 
there</p>
<blockquote>Line 1<br/>Line 2<br/><strong>Line 3</strong><br/>Line 4</blockquote>
```

Comment: Thank you! If it wasn't for the other solution and I've happily used this.